# Android: How to detect end of scroll

Tags: android

I need to implement HorizontalScrollView which is scrolled to predefined positions (similar to Home behaviour). It works with slow gestures, but does not work with neither flings nor arrow key press.

I hooked to View.onScrollChanged() and it is called when scrolling happened, but I can't determine when scrolling animation ends.

In theory there should be a way to say that fling movement is over. Is there such API?

Answer (score 2):

I did not find a way to track scroll animation, but it's possible to move scroll logic from HorizontalScrollView class to derived by you, where you can control every aspect of scrolling

Answer (score 1):

I'm replying to a post a year old but this might be useful for future readers.

For implementing HOME-Like scroll, use `Gallery` instead of `HorizontalScrollView`.
Using 'Gallery' you need not worry about stopping scrolling at predefined positions and it gives you a handler for *Fling-gesture* too.
Add your code in `onFling()` or `onScroll()` as per your requirement.

More info @ http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Gallery.html